# Remove header/filter-button columns from Telerik UI RadDataGrid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, telerik, telerik-grid

Much what the title says. When creating a RadDataGrid using TelerikUI in Xamarin.Forms, we get a "header column".

I know the style of can be set via the HeaderStyle property, and the text itself can be hidden by setting HeaderText to an empty string, but how do we actually remove the row of columns itself? Is this possible, with or without custom renderers?

[image: The columns I'm referring to look like this, once the text has been hidden]

We've tried setting the HeaderStyle to different attributes in hope that it'll fix it (hidden, collapsed etc), we've also tried emptying different properties/tags to try to achieve something similar to CSS's `display: none` but nothing has given us results as of yet. Any and all help appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the dots, you can set the Header Style:

```
<telerikDataGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Country">
    <telerikDataGrid:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <telerikDataGrid:DataGridColumnHeaderStyle OptionsButtonTextColor="Transparent"
                                                   BorderColor="#D9D9D9"
                                                   BorderThickness="1"/>
    </telerikDataGrid:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
</telerikDataGrid:DataGridTextColumn>
```

In addition, if you don't use any sorting or filtering, you can disable it through these properties

```
  UserGroupMode="Disabled"
  UserFilterMode="Disabled"
  UserSortMode="None"
```

Comment: Hiding the dots is a great step in the right direction, but do you happen to know if there's a way to hide the whole row of columns at all?